# Mapstruct ignores @BeanMapping qualifiedByName

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm trying to use separated `@AfterMaping`/`@BeforeMapping` methods for 2 methods: `toDto` and `toPartialDto`, but MapStruct generates code, where all `@AfterMaping`/`@BeforeMapping` methods are used.
I tried rework my abstract class to interface, but the problem remains.

```
    @BeanMapping(qualifiedByName = {"method1", "method2", "method3"})
    public abstract MyDto toDto(MyEntity entity);

    @Named("toPartialDto")
    @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true, qualifiedByName = {"method3", "method4"})
    public abstract MyDto toPartialDto(MyEntity entity);

    @Named("method1")
    @BeforeMapping
    protected void setField1Data(@MappingTarget MyDto target, MyEntity entity) {
       //some code
    }

    @Named("method2")
    @AfterMapping
    protected void updateDto(@MappingTarget MyDto target, MyEntity entity) {
         //some code
    }

    @Named("method3")
    @AfterMapping
    protected void resolveOwn(@MappingTarget MyDto dto) {
       //some code
    }

    @Named("method4")
    @AfterMapping
    protected void mapPartial(@MappingTarget MyDto target, MyEntity entity) {
       //some code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

MapStruct doesn't ignore the `qualifiers`. When you define multiple qualifiers in `BeanMapping#qualifiedByName` MapStruct will try to match all of them. This is mostly meant for having a specific qualified class with qualified methods.

Comment: But why if i use only one element in `qualifiedByName` , then it works correct and does not work with array of names?

Comment: Because that is how MapStruct works. "MapStruct will try to match all of them".  It is not an "or" but an "and". You can read more about it in https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers